# DWR converter for String

Tags: dwr

I use DWR to fetch value from DB. So far I have been using facade as return value and hence i gave like

```
<allow>
 <create creator="new" javascript="dddd">
            <param name="class" value="classname" />
        </create>

        <convert converter="bean"
            match="classname"></convert>
    </allow>
```

Now I want to return a String value. What should I give in the converter="" match="" param name="" and value="" ??? Is there something like String for converter attribute?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

DWR documentation (http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/server/configuration/dwrxml/converters/index.html) states that :

> "**The converters for primitives, strings and simple objects like
>   BigDecimal are all there waiting for you. You don't need a  element in the  section in dwr.xml to use them - They are
>   enabled by default.**
>
> The types enabled by default include: boolean, byte, short, int, long,
>   float, double, char, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Byte,
>   java.lang.Short, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Long, java.lang.Float,
>   java.lang.Double, java.lang.Character, java.math.BigInteger,
>   java.math.BigDecimal, java.util.Collection (implemenations),
>   java.util.Map (implemenations), java.lang.String, etc. For a complete
>   list you can take a look at the dwr.xml which defines all of the
>   default converters (in the dwr.jar)"